# Get result into a string variable in OCaml

Tags: ocaml, frama-c

I have this function working which prints out the value in an offsetmap:

```
let pretty_offsetmap_original lv fmt offsetmap =
  begin match offsetmap with
  | None ->  Format.fprintf fmt "<BOTTOM>"
  | Some off ->
    let typ = Some (typeOfLval lv)
    in
    Format.fprintf fmt "%a%a"
      pretty_lval_or_absolute lv
      (Cvalue.V_Offsetmap.pretty_typ typ) off
end
```

Now I would like to get the value in to a string variable to transform it for my purpose. I replaced `Format.fprintf fmt` by `Printf.sprintf` but it does not work. The compiling error:

```
Error: This expression has type
      Format.formatter -> Cvalue.V_Offsetmap.t -> unit
    but an expression was expected of type unit -> 'a -> string
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, you are correct: `Format.sprintf` does not have the good type. Within Frama-C, the function `Pretty_utils.sfprintf` will do exactly what you need. You may also want to have a look at `Pretty_utils.to_string`.

Answer (score 3):

Seems like you'd need to replace `Format.fprintf` with `Format.sprintf` not with `Printf.sprintf`.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work given the type of `Format.sprintf`. `Format.sprintf "%a"` has type `(unit -> '_a -> string) -> '_a -> string` instead of `(Format.formatter -> '_a -> string) -> '_a -> string`